# Flutter Firestore how to get Last Message from chat conversation?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using Flutter with Cloud Firestore to build chat app, i want user list with last messages

[image]

[image]

i googled and find how to join between two collection and create another list

```
 await Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .getDocuments()
            .then((results) {
          List<Users> users = [];
          results.documents.forEach((doc) {
            Users user = new Users();

            String id = doc.data['id'];
            if (id.hashCode <= currentUserId.hashCode) {
              groupChatId = '$id-$currentUserId';
            } else {
              groupChatId = '$currentUserId-$id';
            }

            user.Id = doc.data['id'];
            user.Name = doc.data['name'];

            Firestore.instance
                .collection('messages')
                .document(groupChatId)
                .collection(groupChatId)
                .getDocuments()
                .then((m) {
              if (m.documents.length > 0) {
                user.LastMessage = m.documents.first.data['content'];
              }
            });

            print(user.LastMessage);

            users.add(user);
          });
          setState(() {
            _users = users;
          });
        });
```

when i print user.LastMessage return null but the _users contain all information but there is message inside _users list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suspicion, I have not tested this:

Inside the second `then` handler, you are fetching a last message, but by the time it arrived, the block finished execution and you are not waiting for it to come back.

Perhaps try like this:

```
void _fetch() async {
  // Wait for all documents to arrive, first.
  final result = await Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .getDocuments();

  List<Users> users = [];

  results.documents.forEach((doc) {
    Users user = new Users();

    String id = doc.data['id'];
    if (id.hashCode <= currentUserId.hashCode) {
      groupChatId = '$id-$currentUserId';
    } else {
      groupChatId = '$currentUserId-$id';
    }

    user.Id = doc.data['id'];
    user.Name = doc.data['name'];

    // Wait for each single message to arrive
    final m = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .document(groupChatId)
        .collection(groupChatId)
        .getDocuments();

    if (m.documents.length > 0) {
      user.LastMessage = m.documents.first.data['content'];
    }

    print(user.LastMessage);

    users.add(user);
  });

  setState(() {
    _users = users;
  });
}
```

However, please note that this approach is inefficient if you have a lot of conversations open.

You could consider using [Future.wait](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-functions-that-return-futures) (you need to replace your `onEach` call with a `map` that returns Futures's).